# Why the callback of http.createserver function runs twice?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I am learning node js and i tried to make a small server like in the given code but on each refresh the word 'here' from console.log('here') gets printed twice I am unable to understand why this is so?

```
const http=require('http');
const server=http.createServer((request,respond)=>{
    console.log('here');
    if(request.url==='/'){
        respond.write('hello world');
        respond.end()
    }
    if(request.url==='/about'){
        respond.write('about page');
        respond.end()
    }
    
});
console.log('here now');
server.listen(5000);
```

Can anyone explain how is this happening.
I know a similar question has been asked earlier and the callback is being called multiple times but why 2 times for single refresh?

Comment: Log the value of `request.url`; it should become obvious (odds on [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon)).

Comment: so how this /favicon.ico came in my url pls explain

Comment: read the linked document: _Only SeaMonkey does not fetch favicon.ico files in the website's root by default._

Comment: You need to learn more about the concepts before use any code sample on the internet. I think the answer to your question is 'this forum is not about teaching like university or anything, it's about collaboration. I think you should start reading or studying at least what you are doing or trying to do, then come back with some ideas or more complex question. Sorry about that. Good luck!"

Answer (score 0):

It's normal your browser is making more than one call

lot's of browsers make call to obtain /favicon.ico for example.

To see what's being called. Try to log the URL:

```
console.log(req.url);
```